# Jmeter Set Relative Path Relative to Jmeter Install in User Defined Variables

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, relative-path, jmeter-plugins

I want to know if there is a way to reference a file in the 'User Defined Variables" of the Test Plan relative to the install of Jmeter? For example instead of having a variable called 'sampleFile' and its value: C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\example.txt I want to have a variable called 'sampleFile' and its value be relative to the install so: ..\bin\example.txt or ..\lib\example.txt. I am asking this because I want to place the script on a server.

Long story short: Can I make paths relative to the install of Jmeter? And if so how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(user.dir,)}
```

See:

- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept
- [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual
- [Java System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to see what else you can use this way

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
 ${__javaScript(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir())}/js/script.js
```

See [example](http://www.fabiouechi.tk/2013/03/how-to-reference-current-jmeter-script.html?m=1)